# What effects would a substance as hot as the sun have on its surroundings on Earth?

Tags: temperature, earth, sun

If you had an object, about the size of an adult human, that was as hot as the surface of the sun that somehow doesn't cool down, what effect would it have on its surroundings? Would it just vapourise everything and fall straight through the ground? What would be a safe distance from it and what would you see from there?

To clarify, the temperature is approximately 5,778 Kelvin (5504.85 Celsius or 9940.73 Fahrenheit) and not made from the sun, just a solid object that is able to replicate the same temperature and remain stable.

Comment: This might be a better fit on [worldbuilding.se] than here. Please take their tour and refer to their help centre - and provide a bit more context and detail if you can.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. lol I thought about posting there but decided against it lol. How do I transfer it? Do I just delete this and post it there?

Answer (score 1):

If this mysterious object doesn’t cool down then it doesn’t transfer heat to its surroundings. If it doesn’t transfer heat to its surroundings then it has no effect on its surroundings. Imagine a very large and very efficient thermos flask filled with molten lava.

Comment: Or, ... drifting into WorldBuilding... the object has a nuclear fusion generator at its center and thus can dump energy for a finite amount of time w/o cooling.  But even in this case we need to specify the spectral reflectance/absorptance of the object's surface to know at what rate it dumps energy into the environment.